# Removing only the duplicate key and value from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I've been searching high and low for this one, I have an array of objects that contain dates and times, I'm looking to remove the duplicate date and keeping the rest of the data in the object.

So...

```
[
    {
      'id': '1',
      'date': '2021-10-01',
      'start': '10:00:00',
      'finish': '12:00:00'
    },
    {
      'id': '2',
      'date': '2021-10-01',
      'start': '13:00:00',
      'finish': '14:00:00'
    },
    {
      'id': '3',
      'date': '2021-10-02',
      'start': '13:00:00',
      'finish': '14:00:00'
    },
    {
      'id': '4',
      'date': '2021-10-03',
      'start': '13:00:00',
      'finish': '14:00:00'
    }
]
```

Would end up like:

```
[
    {
      'id': '1',
      'date': '2021-10-01',
      'start': '10:00:00',
      'finish': '12:00:00'
    },
    {
      'id': '2',
      'start': '13:00:00',
      'finish': '14:00:00'
    },
    {
      'id': '3',
      'date': '2021-10-02',
      'start': '13:00:00',
      'finish': '14:00:00'
    },
    {
      'id': '4',
      'date': '2021-10-03',
      'start': '13:00:00',
      'finish': '14:00:00'
    }
]
```

Simply put I check for the duplicate date and only keep the first original one, removing the rest.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Set` to remember which dates are already encountered, and skip them in following objects:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

If you want to modify the original array:

```js
const dates = new Set;
arr.forEach(item => dates.has(item.date) && delete item.date || dates.add(item.date));

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script>
const arr=[{id:"1",date:"2021-10-01",start:"10:00:00",finish:"12:00:00"},{id:"2",date:"2021-10-01",start:"13:00:00",finish:"14:00:00"},{id:"3",date:"2021-10-02",start:"13:00:00",finish:"14:00:00"},{id:"4",date:"2021-10-03",start:"13:00:00",finish:"14:00:00"}];
</script>
```

If you want to get a new array:

```js
const dates = new Set;
const result = arr.map(({id, date, ...item}) => dates.has(date) && {id, ...item} || dates.add(date) && {id, date, ...item});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const arr=[{id:"1",date:"2021-10-01",start:"10:00:00",finish:"12:00:00"},{id:"2",date:"2021-10-01",start:"13:00:00",finish:"14:00:00"},{id:"3",date:"2021-10-02",start:"13:00:00",finish:"14:00:00"},{id:"4",date:"2021-10-03",start:"13:00:00",finish:"14:00:00"}];
</script>
```

Comment: That's a clever trick for keeping the data from cluttering the JS box of the snippet, I'll have to remember that.

Comment: Even cleaner than what Chatgtp came up with, are you AI? :)